# JQuery OnClick animations and if statements

Tags: jquery, animation, if-statement, fadein, fadeout

I've been spending the last 90 minutes or so trying to figure this out.  I've got a site animated with JQuery, and 2 links that appear at the end of the animation.  When you click on either link, a div fades in to reveal more links.  Everything is working up to this point (for reference, link 1 is "Then" and link 2 is "Now").

What I want to happen is let's say a user clicked on "Then". Now he wants to click "Now". I want the "Then" div to fade out and the "Now" div to fade in.  And vice versa.  I feel like my code is almost there, but I'm a total JS noob and can't seem to get it.  I also don't want to bust up what I've already got trying to figure it out.  Code follows:

```
//then + now animation

var thennav = document.getElementById('#thennavbox');
var nownav = document.getElementById('#nownavbox');

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#then').click(function(){
    $('#thennavbox').fadeIn(1000);
});

$('#now').click(function(){
    $('#nownavbox').fadeIn(1000);
});
});//end onclick animation

if(thennav.style.display=='none'){
    $('#nownavbox').fadeOut(1000, function(){
        $('#thennavbox').fadeIn(1000);
        });
    };

if(nownav.style.display=='none'){
    $('#thennavbox').fadeOut(1000, function(){
        $('#nownavbox').fadeIn(1000);
        });
    };//end if statements

//end then + now animation
```

Like I said, everything fades in as it's supposed to.  I just can't get one to fade out and the other to fade in.  I think perhaps my if statements are in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#then').click(function(){
    $('#thennavbox').fadeIn(1000);
    $('#nownavbox').fadeOut(1000);

});

$('#now').click(function(){
    $('#nownavbox').fadeIn(1000);
    $('#thennavbox').fadeOut(1000);
});
```

Comment: Wow.  It's almost laughably simple, I don't know why I didn't think of it.  I guess my approach was a classic case of "using a bazooka to kill a fly."